# Problem finding library, running Python code from Java

Tags: python, java, raspberry-pi

I have a python script running a BME280 temp/humidity sensor on my Raspberry pi.

I can run the script using python just fine, and I get the expected output.

However, when I try to run it from Java, I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named smbus2
```

The first line of the python script is:

```
from smbus2 import SMBus
```

I have installed the smbus2 library.

If I run pip list, smbus2 is listed.

And the python script runs, using this library  - so why doesn't the python script run just the same when it is called by Java?

The Java finds my python script alright, and the script runs, but instead of sending the temp/humidity values, it sends the error message back to Java saying it can't find the module smbus2.

I would have expected that running the python script from Java would make no difference to python accessing installed python libraries.

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having slept on it after a long day, it became obvious I have 2 pythons on the pi. Calling python3 did the trick